# logging services calls in .txt file

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to user the following code

```
private CModel[] getConfig(string CID, string Program)
        {
            ServiceManagement.ServiceClient obj;
            List<ServiceManagement.ManagementApiRepositoryCConfig> executedService;
            obj = new ServiceManagement.ServiceClient();
            executedService = new List<SaServiceIdentityManagement.ManagementApiRepositoryCConfig>();
            executedService = obj.getClubConfigSingle(CID, Program);

            return executedService.Select(x => new CModel
            {
                CID = CID,
                ProgramName = x.Name,
                ProgramURL = x.Value,
            }).ToArray();
        }
```

and

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("log.txt"))
        {
            Log("call 1", w);
            Log("call 2", w);
        }
```

What I am wanting to do is build a .txt, or xml, js/json file to log requests to the service

I am not sure why Im getting nothing added to the log.txt file

Thanks M

Comment: Is there a special reason why you implement your own logger and not just use an existing one, for example log4net?

Comment: What have you tried? What does or doesn't work? Does your log file get created? Is it just empty? In your call to File.AppendText you are not specifying a directory so you will get the current directory of the process which could be anywhere on the disk.

Comment: its just a empty 0kb file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to build something that already exists by default in the .net framework. I think what you're looking for is the tracing functionality that's in system.diagnostics. Try adding this to your config file:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing"
        propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="C:\logs\TracingAndLogging-client.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
        name="xml" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
```

It's easy and cheap to implement and there's even a special software that displays it neatly for you.

You can find more information about tracing here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526%28v=vs.110%29.aspx